# Why isn't the JButton depressing?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a very simple example. A button on the bottom of the screen that says "hi" and when its clicked it prints "hello" to the console. However, When I press the button, it doesn't change visually. Its the same with the other JSwing interactors, but for a SSCCE, here you go.

```
import acm.program.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleGUI extends ConsoleProgram {

public void init() {
    JButton hi = new JButton("Hi");
    add(hi, SOUTH);
    addActionListeners();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
    if (cmd.equals("Hi")) println("Hello there sexy");
}
}
```

Comment: I think JButton, and Swing in general, is very depressive indeed..

Comment: I was hoping for a joke when I read the title.  Got Swing.  Satisfied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appearance of Swing controls (including buttons) is controlled by the look-n-feel. This includes whether or not buttons look depressed when clicked.

This may help:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Comment: I'm really new to all this. Hence I am learning with the ACM libraries. I looked at the site but it seems like a lot of info. I just want to know why my look and feel is the same even when I change something. For example I have two radio buttons: Big and Small. Small is selected by default, when I click on Big, Small is still visually selected, but the program takes measures according to  Big being selected. Seems like something that should work out of the box. Any other thoughts?

Comment: The radio buttons behavior that you are describing isn't related to look-n-feel. It is a common mistake, though, so ask that as a separate question and someone will help you out.

Comment: Well whatever is causing it is the same problem for all the other JComponents. The JButton doesn't depress, the JCheckBox doesn't check, The JSlider doesn't slide, the Combo box brings up the options but doesn't actually change to the one the user selects. This is only visually though. They all work though, i.e. when I click on the checkBox "Filled" in order to produce a filled circle vs a hollow one when I click in the graphics window, it does that. Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps you are using some extra library on top of Swing that is causing you problems. Since you are just starting out, I'd strip away all layers and make sure that you are learning Swing instead of debugging third-party library issues.

Comment: Like it may be a problem with the ACM library packages? Weird, I am learning Java using them through Stanford online cs106a. In Lecture 20, He codes it and it works for him, but then again, that was in 2007. Maybe the packages and stuff have changed since then. Like I said, I'm just a beginner so I don't know this stuff. If you find anything, please send it over here. Thank you!

Comment: Right. It is conceivable that there is incompatibility between this library and whatever version of Java you are using. Debugging this incompatibility shouldn't be your focus. I recommend starting from a basic Swing tutorial that doesn't require additional libraries. Here is a good resource: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: I tried switched my JRE to a different one and when I loaded it up it works for like a half a second, then freezes. Like if I run my program and click in a JTextBox, and type a whole bunch of characters, it will highlight blue, show like 6 characters I typed and then freeze. When I hit enter it will print what I actually typed to the screen. Just some more symptoms I thought may be helpful for diagnosing. Any thoughts? re-install new JDK?